# ASP.NET Core 3.1 JWT signature invalid when using AddJwtBearer()

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, encryption-asymmetric, jwt

**Problem: `AddJwtBearer()` is failing, but verifying the token manually works.**

I'm trying to generate and verify a JWT with an asymmetric RSA algo.

I can generate the JWT just fine using this demo code

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> JwtBearerToken() {
    AppUser user = await userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    using RSA rsa = RSA.Create(1024 * 2);
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["jwt:privateKey"]), out int _);
    var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new RsaSecurityKey(rsa), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256);

    var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(
        audience: "identityapp",
        issuer: "identityapp",
        claims: new List<Claim>() {new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.UserName)},
        notBefore: DateTime.Now,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddHours(3),
        signingCredentials: signingCredentials
    );

    string token = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index), new {jwt = token});
}
```

I'm also able to verify the token and it's signature using the demo code below

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public IActionResult JwtBearerTokenVerify(string token) {
    using RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(configuration["jwt:privateKey"]), out int _);

    var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    ClaimsPrincipal principal = handler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters() {
        IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
        ValidAudience = "identityapp",
        ValidIssuer = "identityapp",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
    }, out SecurityToken securityToken);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

But, verification fails (401) when hitting an endpoint protected with
`[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]`

Error message from HTTP header: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

My JWT bearer auth configuration is here

```
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    using var rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["jwt:privateKey"]), out int _);
                    
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        IssuerSigningKey = new RsaSecurityKey(rsa),
        ValidAudience = "identityapp",
        ValidIssuer = "identityapp",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,                 
    };
});
```

**I can easily make it work using a symmetric key and HmacSha256 - but that's not what I'm looking for.**

### UPDATE

I've written the exception to the response, and this is what I get:

```
IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried: 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.RsaSecurityKey, KeyId: '', InternalId: '79b1afb2-0c85-43a1-bb81-e2accf9dff38'. , KeyId: 
'.
Exceptions caught:
 'System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'RSA'.
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.ThrowIfDisposed()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.GetDuplicatedKeyHandle()
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.VerifyHash(ReadOnlySpan`1 hash, ReadOnlySpan`1 signature, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.RSAImplementation.RSACng.VerifyHash(Byte[] hash, Byte[] signature, HashAlgorithmName hashAlgorithm, RSASignaturePadding padding)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.VerifyWithRsa(Byte[] bytes, Byte[] signature)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricAdapter.Verify(Byte[] bytes, Byte[] signature)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.AsymmetricSignatureProvider.Verify(Byte[] input, Byte[] signature)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(Byte[] encodedBytes, Byte[] signature, SecurityKey key, String algorithm, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
   at System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityTokenHandler.ValidateSignature(String token, TokenValidationParameters validationParameters)
'.
token: '{"alg":"RS256","typ":"JWT"}.{"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier":"mail@mail.com","nbf":1582878368,"exp":1582889168,"iss":"identityapp","aud":"identityapp"}'.
```

### UPDATE - Working solution

So, I guess I figured it out from the exception message. The RSA security key was being prematurely disposed.

I extracted the key creation from the `AddJwtBearer()`, and used dependency injection instead.

This seems to work just fine. But I'm unsure if this is good practice.

```
// Somewhere futher up in the ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) method
services.AddTransient<RsaSecurityKey>(provider => {
    RSA rsa = RSA.Create();
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(
        source: Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["jwt:privateKey"]),
        bytesRead: out int _);
                
        return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});


// Chaining onto services.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    SecurityKey rsa = services.BuildServiceProvider().GetRequiredService<RsaSecurityKey>();
                    
        options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters() {
        IssuerSigningKey = rsa,
        ValidAudience = "identityapp",
        ValidIssuer = "identityapp",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
    };

});
```

Answer (score 6):

While your solution apparently works, it has two issues, for which I'll provide solutions.

The first issue is that the `RSA` you create implements `IDisposable`, but the disposing is not handled properly within the life cycle (here: transient) since the `RSA` is not the immediate result of a factory. This results in a resource leak where undisposed RSA instances might accumulate throughout the running time of you host (and even beyond the "official" shutdown).

The second issue is that your use of `BuildServiceProvider` creates a whole new service provider additionally to the one implicitly used by the rest of the code. In other words, this creates a new dependency injection container in parallel to the "canonical" one.

The solution goes as follows. (Note I can't test your scenario perfectly, but I have something similar in my own application.) I'll start with the key part in the middle:

```
services
.AddTransient(provider => RSA.Create())
.AddTransient<SecurityKey>(provider =>
{
    RSA rsa = provider.GetRequiredService<RSA>();
    rsa.ImportRSAPrivateKey(source: Convert.FromBase64String(Configuration["jwt:privateKey"]), bytesRead: out int _);
    return new RsaSecurityKey(rsa);
});
```

Note how the `RSA` gets its own factory. So it is disposed at the right time. The security key too has its own factory, which looks up the `RSA` when needed.

Somewhere *above* the code I just showed, you would do something like this:

```
services
.AddOptions<JwtBearerOptions>(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.Configure<SecurityKey>((options, signingKey) =>
{
    options.IncludeErrorDetails = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
        ValidAudience = "identityapp",
        ValidIssuer = "identityapp",
        RequireExpirationTime = true,
        RequireAudience = true,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
    };
});

services
    .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
    .AddJwtBearer();
```

Note how the `TokenValidationParameters` were moved inside a `Configure` method! The `signingKey` there will be the `SecurityKey` you registered on the dependency injection container! Thus we get rid of `BuildServiceProvider`.

Caution: Microsoft's IdentityModel seems to have a bug where using an `RSA`, disposing it, and then using another `RSA` fails under certain circumstances for the second `RSA` instance. This is for example the underlying issue behind [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67484943/every-other-request-jwt-validation-fails-with-idx10503-signature-validation-fai). You might run into that issue independently of my solution. But you may sidestep that issue by adding your `RSA` (not necessarily the security key) with `AddSingleton` rather than `AddTransient`.